# How to Disable Plank

Tags: plank, dconf

In Elementary OS Luna, I was able to disable Plank by going into the dconf settings and removing Plank from the `monitored-processes` in `org.pantheon.cerbere`. I installed the newer Freya and now this won't work. How do I disable Plank?

Uninstalling Plank isn't really an option since IIRC it messes with other dependencies that I have of already installed.

**P.S.**: Yep, it removes elementary tweaks if I try to uninstall plank, which I don't want.

```
jonathan@jonathan-elementary:~$ sudo apt-get remove plank
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gtk3-engines-unico libgrip0 libtimezonemap1 plank-theme-pantheon sbsigntool
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  elementary-tweaks plank
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1,473 kB disk space will be freed.
```

Comment: I'm running the latest release, and this still works flawlessly. Can you describe the steps you perform to disable Plank?

Comment: What still works flawlessly? The config modification?

Comment: Yes, removing plank from the monitored processes.

Comment: This is literally my `monitored-processes` config: `['wingpanel', 'slingshot-launcher --silent']`. I reset my computer and the thing is still there.

Comment: I dont' quite get what you mean by "I reset my computer". What you should simply do after modifying the string in Dconf is killing Plank with "killall plank".

Comment: Doesn't really matter either way I do it afaik.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The configuration was changed from `org.pantheon.cerbere` to `org.pantheon.desktop.cerbere`:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-pantheon/cerbere/cerbere/revision/49

So I just modified the `monitored-processes` from there and I was able to disable Plank no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Plank > preferences > chose position=top + auto hide options. You'll never see the plank again.

Comment: how do I bring it back now?
I removed it and installed it again still not seeing it